# I want to dynamically add DIV after the iteration is running the forth time. This DIV will put a page break

Tags: angular

I am sharing the HTML code which has to be written in Angular2 , it has divs and each div will be generated with the help of an iterator. Now after each four div I want to add another container div over the four divs, this DIV that will put a page break into the code which I am going to print.

I have a code where I want to print 4 records per page using anuglar2. Now how to interate in a way where i put a container div over the four divs. Sample code that i want to produce is shown below.

Eg.

```
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="innerdiv1"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv2"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv3"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv4"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="innerdiv5"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv6"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv7"></div>
  <div class="innerdiv8"></div>
</div>
```

Now i am printing the inner divs with iterations, but after 4 inner divs I want it to be encapsulated with a "container-div"

Comment: Can you show the function to generate the divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let s of myarray; let i=index;">


  <div *ngIf="i%4 == 0">
      <div style="page-break-before: always"></div>
  </div>    

  <div [ngClass]="(i%4==0)?'class1':'class2'">{{s}}</div>


</ng-container>
```

Comment: Although i wasn't able to encapsulate the page-break div, but yes simply inserting the page-break-div after the 4 iteration worked for page breaks.